# Photoshop: Export layers in multiple PSD files to PNGs?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I have about 300 PSD files, each with 2 layers, and I'd like to export the top most layer in each file (e.g., named 'Layer 1') to PNG. Is there a way to batch export certain layers in a collection of PSD files to uniquely named PNGs?

Comment: I'm thinking you probably need to script it.

Comment: If there're always two layers, what do you mean by "export certain layers"? And how pngs should be named?

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy Yes, there are always 2 layers in my particular case. I'm flexible with how the PNGs are named, as long as they're unique.

Comment: So you can just create an action that'd diable the second layer and save a copy of the current file as png? the name will be the same as psd

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy But if I use an action, I'd need to apply the action to each file individually, right? I'm trying to do it automatically and apply some sort of batch export.

Comment: You can run actions on all opened documents or on a folder with images (File > Automate > Batch)

Comment: @SergeyKritskiy Oh right. I'll give that a try. Thanks.

Comment: I'll create an answer from this discussion

Answer (score 1):

Since all your layers have the same structure, you can create an Action that'll hide the bottom layer. Then use `File > Automation > Batch` menu command to apply this action to files from a specific folder and save the result to a different folder.